# Finding the two different conjugacy classes in $A_n$ after splitting criterion

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

Suppose we have a group $A_n$ for some $n$ (maybe take $A_5$ as an example).

We find the conjugacy classes of $S_n$ which are determined by cycle type. Then we use the splitting criterion ,http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Splitting_criterion_for_conjugacy_classes_in_the_alternating_group, as we find a conjugacy class that splits, eg that represented by $(12345)$ in $S_5$.

Is there a way of computing/spotting the two conjugacy classes. One will be $(12345)$ but is there a way of getting the other preferably without doing any calculations.

Looking for general method.

Comment: General comment. For $H\leq G$ finite group, and $x\in G$ we have $x^G\cap H=\bigcup_{i\leq|G:H|}x_i^H$. I'm not aware of a general method, apart from the 'brute force' one: checking if there are two permutations in $x^{S_n}$ that are not $A_n$-conjugate.

Comment: I'm not certain about this, but I suspect $x$ and $x^{-1}$ will be in different conjugacy classes in the situation you describe.

Comment: Thats the sort of thing I was thinking but I cannot see any justification

Comment: @GerryMyerson: $(2,5)(3,4)$ conjugates $x=(1,2,3,4,5)$ to $x^{-1}$. But $x^2$ is in the other class in $S_5$.

Comment: So GerryMyerson's idea is false

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The class of $g \in S_n$ splits into two classes in $A_n$ if and only if all cycles of $g$ have odd length and their lengths are all distinct (this includes cycles of length $1$).

In a class that splits, you get an element in the other class by conjugating by any odd permutation, such as $(1,2)$.

Comment: Sir just trying to figure out why conjugating by any odd permutation will give the other conjugacy class in $A_n$. We know $S_n$ acts transitively on the $2$ conjugacy classes of $(1 2 3 4 5)$ in $A_n$, moreover which are of equal size. This induces a surjective group homomorphism $\phi:S_n \to \mathbb{Z}_2$ with $\ker(\phi)=A_n$. Hence every element in $S_n \setminus A_n$ gives a nontrivial permutations of two conjugacy classes in $A_n$.

Comment: This is worth mentioning that above is applicable only if $n=5$ or $6$.